# Psycopg2.connect: database does not exist

Tags: psycopg2

When running **psycopg2.connect** as follows:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname="learning", user="postgres",   
password="xxxxx", host="localhost", port="5434")
```

I get "**database does not exist**":

```
File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
--// function from above) //--- 
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/
site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "learning" does not exist
```

However, if I point to "postgres" (i.e. same code, dbname="postgres") the command yields *no errors*.

Understanding that the postgres DB has special functionality, I am unable to find any overt differences in the settings for postgres and learning,  other than that the activity status for postgres is "active", whereas the activity status for "learning" is idle.

Any recommendations how to fix the connection problem appreciated!

Details: python 3.6.5, pagadmin4, postgreSQL(10), MacOSX 10.13.3. *My install of psycopg2 yielded a warning about the wheel package.  Happy to share if relevant.

Comment: Your error message suggests a typo in the code that made the connection?

Comment: Apologies - typo fixed. Results same.  Issue still unresolved

Comment: Can you connect to the "learning" db by other means such as PGAdmin? and why port 5434 have you got multiple instances of postgresql running?

Comment: Thanks Slumdog.  Looked into the "multiple instances" clue, was able to identify another instance of postgreSQL running (which had taken the 5432 port).  Shut that down and removed via brew uninstall, and was able to get things working!

Comment: Excellent happy it helped